# Why didn't this java 8 example using type inference compile in Eclipse?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am reading the newly released Java 8 in Action and found there is a piece of code pasted from Chapter 5 not compiling:

```
    List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
    List<int[]> pairs =
    numbers1.stream()
    .flatMap((Integer i) -> numbers2.stream()
    .map(j -> new int[]{i, j})
    )
    .collect(toList());
```

Eclipse says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<Object>` to `List<int[]>`"

And after comparing with what the author gave on Github, the following compiled:

```
    List<Integer> numbers1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> numbers2 = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
    List<int[]> pairs =
    numbers1.stream()
    .flatMap((Integer i) -> numbers2.stream()
    .map((Integer j) -> new int[]{i, j})
    )
    .collect(toList());
```

The only change is from "j" to "(Integer j)".

But isn't the first version completely equivalent to the second with the syntax sugar provided by Java 8? Why does Java refuse to compile it?

Thanks

BTW:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Comment: *Argh* this is printed in a book?!

Comment: Not entirely. Modified a little bit to make the question obvious.

Comment: Edited the title to reflect that the root cause is in Eclipse.

Comment: To add a bit of reasoning: I find `List<int[]>` a... suboptimal representation of a list of Integer tuples.

Comment: @tilois You are right, I wish Scala tuples could be used here. Actually this piece of code is from the answer of a quiz in the book, and the author said in the question: "For simplicity, you can represent a pair as an array with two elements."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, correcting your terminology: when you say *syntax sugar*, what you really are asking about is *type inference*, that when asked to infer a type for `j` in the inner lambda, that the compiler fails to come up with the right type.

Second, correcting your data: The error messages you cite are not coming from the JDK compiler; they're coming from Eclipse.

This is just an Eclipse bug.  The reference compiler (`javac` from Oracle JDK) handles your first example just fine.

Comment: +1 and adding a further diagnostic bit: `Stream<int[]> pairs =  numbers1.stream().flatMap(i -> numbers2.stream().map(j -> new int[] {i, j}));` compiles fine, so only the last step (`.collect()`) is where the inference fails.

Comment: Confirmed it is just about Eclipse. javac created the class file just fine. Thanks/

Comment: Any word on how to get Eclipse to play nice with these Lambdas?