# Type mismatch ERROR when using recover()

Tags: java, playframework, lambda, java-8, playframework-2.3

Consider the following 2 controllers written using *Play Framework 2.3.8*:

Java8 lambdas:

```
public static Promise<Result> testLambda() {
    final Promise<Boolean> promiseBool = Promise.promise(() -> "TEST".equals("test"));

    return promiseBool.map(bool -> ok()).recover(t -> badRequest());
}
```

"Normal":

```
public static Promise<Result> test() {
    final Promise<Boolean> promiseBool = Promise.promise(new Function0<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply() throws Throwable {
            return "TEST".equals("test");
        }
    });

    return promiseBool.map(new Function<Boolean, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Boolean bool) throws Throwable {
            return ok();
        }
    }).recover(new Function<Throwable, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
            return badRequest();
        }
    });
}
```

The controller written using lambdas gives me this ERROR in eclipse: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from F.Promise<Results.Status> to F.Promise<Result>` while the second one doesn't. This happens only when using the `recover()` function.

On the other hand, **sbt** compiles the code without complaining.

**Question:** Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

For others searching for a -> **REASON:**

Based on [Salem's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205368/salem) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853988/why-didnt-this-java-8-example-using-type-inference-compile-in-eclipse) answer: This is an ***Eclipse bug*** and has nothing to do with type inference or other <*insert you favourite Java bashing here*>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4124) related to this in Play Framework but from the discussion it seems that this is more a problem of Java than Play itself. The workaround would be something like this (credit to [igmar](https://github.com/igmar)):

```
return promiseBool.map(new Function<Boolean, Result>() {
    @Override
    public Result apply(Boolean bool) throws Throwable {
        Result res = ok();
        return res;
    }
}).recover(new Function<Throwable, Result>() {
    // Same
});
```

Using `return (Result) ok();` may also work.

Comment: If that works, `bool -> (Result)ok()` should work as well, shouldn’t it? But it’s the first time I hear that Java should have problems with covariant return types. I can understand, if it’s an Eclipse issue as it has plenty of problems with Java 8 but blaming Java in general looks like a thin claim. Maybe it would help to know where the `ok()` method does come from and how its signature looks like…

Comment: Indeed (Result) ok() works as well. You might be right about the Java bashing... will investigate and return with an update if I find something.

Comment: On the other hand we can blame the type inference in Java as a whole. Not the sharpest pencil...

Comment: Investigated -> added reason to my question. Maybe you can add it to your answer as well. Redundancy FTW!