# Stream List values into Map.Entry.values

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for a way to `Stream` a `List` into a `Map` where I can specify the key.

For example say I have two lists:

```
List<String> one = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
List<String> two = Arrays.asList("100","200","300");
```

I am looking for a way to `Stream` them into a `Map<String, List<String>>`

```
{
  "below 100" : ["1","2","3"],
  "above 100" : ["100","200","300"]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
Stream.of(
  one.stream(),
      .collect(Collectors.toMap("below 100", ??)
  ,
  two.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap("above 100", ??)
 )
 .reduce(Stream::concat)
```

Comment: Look for 'Collectors.toMap'

Comment: I did, but I cannot specify my own key for some reason.  I get a cast issue

Comment: This example doesn't make a lot of sense. You already have two lists properly organized. Why not create a map and `map.put("below 100", one); map.put("above 100", two);`? Where does the stream come in?

Comment: I cannot change the methods interface return type which is `Stream`.  So I need to return a `Stream` of `Map<String,List<String>>`

Comment: @Dan, are you using Eclipse? Cast issue in this case is a bug:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853988/why-didnt-this-java-8-example-using-type-inference-compile-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 2 similar ways. In both ways, we seperately transform each List into Map> and then join both Maps. First option is shorter and uses inline Collector, while second one creates a new Collector class.

For both options, we first declare the lists:

```
    List<String> one = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    List<String> two = Arrays.asList("100", "200", "300");
```

1. Shorter option with inline Collector:

   ```
   private BinaryOperator<List<String>> addToList() {
       return (list, str) -> {
           ((ArrayList<String>) list).addAll(str);
           return list;
       };
   }

   Map<String, List<String>> map = Stream.of(
           // first list
           one.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                           l -> "below 100", 
                           // we need List as map value
                           l -> Stream.of(l).collect(Collectors.toList()), 
                           // merge function
                           addToList(), 
                           // provide HashMap for result 
                           HashMap::new 
                   // we can't stream collected Map directly, only through EntrySet
                   )).entrySet(),
           // second list
           two.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                           l -> "above 100", 
                           l -> Stream.of(l).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                           addToList(), 
                           HashMap::new 
                   )).entrySet()
           )
           // extract Entry<String, List<String>> 
           .flatMap(entrySet -> entrySet.stream())
            // convert Entry<String, List<String>> to Map<String, List<String>
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                   entry -> entry.getKey(),
                   entry -> entry.getValue()));
   ```
2. Option using Custom Collector:

Original stream code is shorter and just calls ListToMapCollector instead of implementing inline Collector.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = Stream
            .of(
                    one.stream()
                            // use custom ListToMapCollector
                            .collect(new ListToMapCollector("below 100"))
                            // we can't stream collected Map directly, only through EntrySet
                            .entrySet(), 
                    two.stream()
                            .collect(new ListToMapCollector("above 100"))
                            .entrySet()) 
            // extract Entry<String, List<String>> 
            .flatMap(entrySet -> entrySet.stream())
             // convert Entry<String, List<String>> to Map<String, List<String>
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    entry -> entry.getKey(),
                    entry -> entry.getValue()));
```

And the ListToMapCollector, I used [this tutorial](http://blog.indrek.io/articles/creating-a-collector-in-java-8/) when creating it:

```
     public class ListToMapCollector implements Collector<String, Map<String, 
     List<String>>, Map<String, List<String>>>
    {
    private String mapKey;

    public TestCollector(String string)
    {
        this.mapKey = string;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, List<String>>> supplier() {
        // provide HashMap for result
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, List<String>>, String> accumulator() {
        return (map, stringValue) -> {
            if (!map.containsKey(mapKey))
            {
                map.put(mapKey, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            map.get(mapKey).add(stringValue);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, List<String>>> combiner() {
        // Needed for parrallel stream, excluded for brevity.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, List<String>>, Map<String, List<String>>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.singleton(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
Stream.of(
  one.stream(),
  two.stream()
)
.reduce(Stream::concat)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> {
   // if s > 100 then stuff otherwise other stuff
}, Function.identity());
```

Not sure if I have understand your problem well, but you can try something like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("Below 100", new ArrayList<String>());
map.put("Above 100", new ArrayList<String>());

List one = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
List two = Arrays.asList("100","200","300");

one.stream().forEach(s -> map.get("Below 100").add(s));
two.stream().forEach(s -> map.get("Above 100").add(s));
```

Or alternatively, you can put some more advance code into your stream function:

```
one.stream().forEach(s -> {
   // if value > 100 put in here,
   // Otherwise do stuff...
});
```

Comment: This would not work.  Think of it this way.  I have two `List`s and I need to source them.  I am looking to keep the for a way to index into that list by a user defined key